# Azure Log Analytics: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm trying to build a Log Analytics Workbook using Parameters. One of the parameters is not being recognized by the workbook.

Whats going on here?

**Example:**

- Using `{STORAGE_ACCOUNT:label}` as Parameter results in:
- Error: `" operator:Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named '<storageaccountname>'...`
- [image]
- Hardcoding `<storageaccountname>` in the query results in no error
- [image]

Answer (score 1):

when using single value parameters like `{STORAGE_ACCOUNT:label}`, you still need to enclose them in quotes (either single or double) to make them valid strings:

```
let varStorageAccount = '{STORAGE_ACCOUNT:label}';
```

you're doing that in the example when you hardcode the string.

when using *multi-value* parameters (like multiselect dropdowns), then the quote and delimiter settings are part of that parameter itself.  but for single value parameters like text or single select dropdown, there's no quotes by default, so that the parameters can represent things that wouldn't normally be quoted.